# How can I merge two dataset one column will be between two columns?

Tags: r, merge, inner-join

Hi I want to merge two dataframes (d1 and d2), the rule is same rows in columns d1 and d2 and d2's St1 and St2 will be between dt1's St1 and St2. the expected output and inputs are below. Thanks

```
dt1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), X=c("a","b","c","d"), St1=c(1000,900, 1500, 2500), St2=c(2000,3000, 1800, 4000))
dt2<-data.frame(ID=c(1,4,3,2), X=c("a","e","c","f"), St1=c(1200,2700, 1900, 2000), St2=c(1800,9000, 2650, 2200))

    dt_Exp<-data.frame(ID=c(1), X=c("a"), St1.x=c(1000), 
   St2.x=c(2000),St1.y=c(1200), St2.y=c(1800))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two dataframes using `inner_join`, then using the `by` function to group the merge by similar columns.

Such as:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4), X=c("a","b","c","d"), St1=c(1000,900, 1500, 2500), St2=c(2000,3000, 1800, 4000))
dt2<-data.frame(ID=c(1,4,3,2), X=c("a","e","c","f"), St1=c(1200,2700, 1600, 2000), St2=c(1800,9000, 1650, 2200))

dt_Exp<-data.frame(ID=c(1,3), X=c("a","c"), St1.x=c(1000,1500), St2.x=c(2000, 1800),St1.y=c(1200,1600), St2.y=c(1800, 1650))
dt21

dat <- inner_join(dt1, dt2, by = c("X", "ID"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Lime I think you misunderstood me, yes we have to use `inner_joint'` , but how to add the `between` function to the `inner_joint'`,  I changed the example, the expected output is now different

Comment: It looks to me like you have just merged the two columns, side by side, and what is displayed is the first row when columns are merged side-by-side. Unless, you mean that the columns of `dt2` must be between the first column of `dt1` and the last column of `dt1`. If that is the case, then you can just, whilst using my code or your code, manipulate the columns in the dataframe using `dat <- dat[, 1, 3, 4, 2]`, which orders `dt2` columns `st1` & `st2` between `dt1` columns. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sqldf)

dt_Exp<-sqldf("select * from dt1 inner join dt2 on dt1.ID = dt2.ID and dt1.X=dt2.X where dt2.St1 between dt1.St1 and dt1.St2  and dt2.St2 between dt1.St1 and dt1.St2")
```

Comment: @ doesn't work in question & answer posts & isn't appropriate there. Also code-only answers are discouraged, explain why it answers the question. [ask] [answer] [help]

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear from the whether the merge should match just ID or match both ID and X, so here are two possibilities:

```
> merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("ID","X"))
  ID X St1.x St2.x St1.y St2.y
1  1 a  1000  2000  1200  1800
2  3 c  1500  1800  1900  2650

> merge(dt1, dt2, by=c("ID"))
  ID X.x St1.x St2.x X.y St1.y St2.y
1  1   a  1000  2000   a  1200  1800
2  2   b   900  3000   f  2000  2200
3  3   c  1500  1800   c  1900  2650
4  4   d  2500  4000   e  2700  9000
```

The difference is in the names of the 'by'-arguments which can be given as a character vector when using base R's `merge`-function. (No need for added packages.)